# "Burst" / "Has burst" / "Is burst"

Tags: tense

I am wondering which choice sounds idiomatic and natural here?

- Who are you calling?
- I'm calling a plumber!
- How come?!
- We have a burst here; the water pipe.........

**a.** has burst (doesn't seem to be correct! Because something happened in the past and not have been continued to the now. So the PP tense sounds to be incorrect here.) 
**b.** is burst (I have no idea if it is (in)correct!) 
**c.** burst (I have no idea if it is (in)correct!)

Please let me know which choice works here and which ones don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural would be, "The pipe has burst."

Present perfect *can* be used to talk about something that started in the past and continues to now, but it has many other functions, including something that happened in the past and has a present result. "The pipe has burst" means there is a burst pipe now.

"The pipe is burst" is unnatural, and possibly ungrammatical.

"The pipe burst" is grammatical, and describes something that happened in the past. In the context of water coming out of a pipe where it shouldn't, it clearly as the same intent as using the present perfect, so is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say, "We have a burst here".  I would say, "We have a burst pipe here."  After saying that, it would no longer make sense to say "The water pipe has burst."   But if I were to say that, that's how I would say it.

Answer (score 1):

I would never say

> We have a burst here.

and if I heard or read that, I would be unsure of the meaning. I suspect this might be more common in other varieties of English than AmE, but I am not at all sure.

I might well say any of:

> - The water pipe has burst.
> - The water pipe is broken.
> - The water pipe is busted.
> - A pipe has burst.
> - There is a broken pipe here.
> - There is a serious leak here.
> - The water pipes have frozen..

The past tense form ("has burst")  seems acceptable to me because this is describing a past event, although a pretty recent one. The pipe did burst at some particular time, now in the past.

I would not say "the pipe is burst" and I would think it a bit odd if I heard it, but I would understand it. I can't think of any rule this violates.